# stuck in Android drawable importer

Tags: android-studio, plugins, android-drawable-importer

I downloaded Android drawable importer, but when i clicked  + button  after click batch drawable importer and paste png file, nothing is displayed how can i go through this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled through it too. As it turns out, by Android Studio 3.6.1 this plugin began to not working anymore. As of now, you can use Android Assets studios over the web, like [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example) and [this](https://appicon.co/#image-sets) one.

Comment: I don't understand why the moderator deleted my previous answer, it was unique and I didn't find any other good answer in this matter so I answered as I only wanted to help. How can someone ever post answers to a question if these things happen?